# :hover для элементов в jQuery custom content scroller

Tags: jquery

Использую [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/), в этом скроллере у меня список ссылок и когда я навожу на одну из ссылок и кручу ролик мишки :hover все равно остается на этой ссылке, а вот когда я шевельну мишкой, тогда уже :hover меняется

[Вот тут](http://tankist10.hosting-test.org.ua/) это видно(слева меню).
Как сделать так, чтоб :hover сразу изменялся?

Comment: ul не может содержать div, может в этом проблема ?

Comment: хотя он и так глючит: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/9WLN9/ думаю дело в том, что они используют position вместо scroll, не знаю даже почему, попробуйте другой плагин.